# When will 2016's community promotion ads start being shown?

Tags: discussion, community-promotion-ads

Several sites have some community promotion ads which have reached the threshold, but the old 2015 ads are still being shown. When will the 2016 ads start being shown?

- [English](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7606/59258)
- [Sci-Fi & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7946/17815)
- [Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5856/6071)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14925/333388)
- [Movies & TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2089/18440)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6539/23788)
- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3850/472)
- [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2902/28)

Comment: We asked this on the M&TV CPA post and got no response. I feel that Grace has a lot going on, since the posts still all say 40 KB despite them bumping the limit up to 150.

Comment: 6-8 years, and it will start showing. No worry. :)

Comment: Probably never - there must have been a change in policy.

Comment: @Deer is correct, but after all Stack Exchange needs money, so it's natural they'll prefer ads that raise traffic (more traffic means each external ad cost more to the publisher) and of course external ads.

Comment: FWIW, I'm seeing the 2016 versions on Christianity.SE now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Community ads for 2016 were not set up on any site till recently, as result of the change to the width of the sidebar. Many community ads needed to be reworked in order to fit the new width and we took the position that we would wait until these were ready before we re-enabled them across the board.

This happened yesterday. We now have 59 sites with a community ad thread on their child-meta - these have all been enabled and the sites should show qualifying ads.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the new ads were *briefly* live but aren't now.  On the day the stats link was edited into the ad posts five ads on Worldbuilding met the threshold and [show a few clicks](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2902).  At the same time, two ads met the threshold on Mi Yodeya and [show a few clicks](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3850), but three more ads that *later* met the threshold have 0 clicks.  I'm guessing they were live for a day or so before stopping; whether that was intentional or accidental I do not know.

I'm still seeing the 2015 ads on the several sites.

Edit 2016-03-09 ~01:00 UTC: I'm now seeing 2016 ads on Mi Yodeya and all the ads report a few clicks, which is a change from when I posted this answer.

Comment: You're lucky, I'm [not seeing any ads at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276513/152859) - not even one single community promotion ad.

Answer (score 1):

They are currently live on some sites right now. I see [one of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIHiq.png) on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) (For Mythology.SE).

I do not see them on some of the other sites I visit (that have ads with sufficient upvotes).

Comment: [answer](/help/how-to-answer) Testing? [comment](/help/privileges/comment) [chat]